# Place parallel table columns that are inside separate div's aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div's, one above the other and both have a table inside them with the same amount of columns. I want the columns to be the same width size in both and aligned. If a columns in on div expands, i want the column parallel in the other div to expand to the same with.

NB: The Columns have no width.
[Link to the HTML code below:](http://jsfiddle.net/nathan406/gwUFb/)

---

HTML:

```
<div id="A">
   <table>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <th></th>
               <th>Blah! Blah</th>
               <th>adsdsdadasdasdasdasd</th>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="B">
   <table>
       <tr>
          <th>left head</th>
          <td class="col1"></td>
          <td class="col2">Hello World!</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <th>left head</th>
          <td class="col1">Hello World!</td>
          <td class="col2">dsfsdfgdsgdsgdsfgdsgdsgfdfgdf</td>
       </tr>       
   </table>
</div>
```

---

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#updatetopdiv').click(function(){        
            //Properly align parallel div's top to bottom 
            var tbl1 = $("#A table tr td");
            var tbl2 = $("#B table tr td");
            tbl1.each(function(i) {
                if (tbl2.eq(i).width() < $(this).width()) {
                    tbl2.eq(i).width($(this).width());
                } else {
                    $(this).width(tbl2.eq(i).width());
                }
            });
     });
});​
```

​

Comment: I dont quite understand you want the inside of the cells to have the same amount of space so they are all uniform nomatter what the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
   var tbl1 = $("#A table tr td");
   var tbl2 = $("#B table tr td");
    tbl1.each(function(i){
        if (tbl2.eq(i).width() < $(this).width()){            
           tbl2.eq(i).width($(this).width());
        } else {
           $(this).width(tbl2.eq(i).width()); 
        }    
    });
});​
```

This works, though it doesn't run until load.

Also placed here: http://jsfiddle.net/gwUFb/3/

EDIT:

I know you said you already got it working, but here's my original code, edited for your use case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var tbl1 = $("#A table tr th");
   var tbl2 = $("#B table tr td,#B table tr th");
    tbl1.each(function(i){
        if (tbl2.eq(i).width() < $(this).width()){            
           tbl2.eq(i).width($(this).width());
        } else {
           $(this).width(tbl2.eq(i).width()); 
        }    
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for is post. Edit my example to include what you sent. Please see the html to get the real idea of what I want to accomplish.

Comment: I will edit this.. I'm assuming you want the lower <table> to reflect the width of the above table "headings"

Comment: I was able to use this to get it done: 
 $("#A table tr").children();
 $("#B table tr").children();

But this wasnt able to solve my real problem. Please see this link for my real issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathan406/Dgjct/

Comment: Hmm. What was the real issue? You're trying to keep the header visible when they scroll?

Comment: Yes i would like to keep is visible while scrolling. So what I intend on doing getting the header for the a table inside a div and put it inside another table inside a div. However i want the columns to be the exact same size. I believe I am very close to getting is done.

I tried other tools however this table is render and makes it difficult to use those tools (JQuery plugins)

Comment: What you need to do is move the top two rows of your lower table into your upper table. They are in the lower table still in your example. Then remove the function on "scrolling" and leave the load. Set a max height on the div containing the lower table.

Comment: I did that using JQuery in the -- scroll(function(){...});

Comment: What i mean is... You don't need anything so complicated. See: [http://jsfiddle.net/Dgjct/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/Dgjct/9/)

Comment: Well the issue with this is that this table is rendered from a .net schedule control and this forces me to manipulate it to fix the header from the frontend

Comment: Cris can edit that last example you sent to me and include left header that is fixed also on each row: http://jsfiddle.net/Dgjct/9/

Comment: Didn't quite get the css right for it (when it wraps, the rows don't quite line up.) Hopefully you can play with it a little bit and make it work. [http://jsfiddle.net/zP6rU/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/zP6rU/1/)

Comment: Hi Cris, I was able to get it done but am having issues realigning headers to table when the table expanse. http://jsfiddle.net/nathan406/HP2GZ/

Answer (score 0):

html will be:

```
<div id="A">
   <table class="fixed-table">
       <tr>
          <td class="column-a">Hello World!</td>
          <td class="column-b"></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="B">
   <table class="fixed-table">
       <tr>
          <td class="column-a"></td>
          <td class="column-b">Hello World!</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

css will be

```
.fixed-table {
   table-layout: fixed;
}

.column-a {
    width: 50%;
}

.column-b {
   width: 50%;
}
```

this is a fixed solution, not dynaimic, if any div scroll appears, alignment break. for this you have to use javascript.